# How can I convert numbers into scientific notation?

Tags: javascript, html, math, scientific-notation

I want to make a function that takes an entered value and converts it to scientific notation (N x 10^a)

I've tried many different things, but I can't seem to get it right.

Example:

I enter 200. The converter converts it to 2 x 10^2

Comment: Would also like more specific information. i.e how many significant digits is the max? 2,121,212 -> 2 x 10^6 or 2.1 x 10^6 etc etc? What's the "cut off" I guess

Answer (score 74, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
a = 200
a.toExponential(); //output 2e+2
```

fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/Q8avJ/9/

Comment: Awesome! But is there a way to make it in the form N x 10^a? I can still make do with this, though!

Comment: @Samar You can use string substitution to replace e with x 10 if you want, even though they mean the same thing

Comment: [`toExponential`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toExponential) also takes a `digits` argument like `toFixed`, to control how many digits the fractional part (before the `e`)! `

Answer (score 13):

At some point I wanted to use the coefficient and the exponent as numbers.

If you want to do that, you can use `toExponential` function, split the string and convert the items of the array to numbers.

In the following snippet I assign the numbers to the `numInSciNot` object and print them in the wanted format.

```js
const num = 200;
const numInSciNot = {};
[numInSciNot.coefficient, numInSciNot.exponent] =
  num.toExponential().split('e').map(item => Number(item));
 
console.log(`${numInSciNot.coefficient} x 10^${numInSciNot.exponent}`);
```

If you don't want to use them as numbers you can just use `replace`:

```js
const num = 200;
 
console.log(num.toExponential().replace(/e\+?/, ' x 10^'));
```

In this snippet I've used RegExp to replace `e` or `e+`(in the case of positive exponent).

If you want to specify the number of digits after the decimal point, you can use `toExponential(NumberOfDigits)` in the above examples.

Comment: thanks, that's exactly what I wanted. Surprised this isn't part of the standard lib. You can also use point-free style like this: `num.toExponential().split('e').map(Number)`

Answer (score 2):

If you want a base 10 format like this:

*m* x 10<sup>*n*</sup>

Then you can use a function like this:

```
function writeScientificNum(p_num, p_precision) {
    var n = Math.round(Math.log10(a));
    var m = (p_num * (Math.pow(10,Math.abs(n)))).toFixed(p_precision);
    document.getElementById("outputTxt").innerHTML = m.toString() + ' x 10<sup>' + n.toString() + '</sup>';
}
```

Test it out: http://jsfiddle.net/u1hd4zm9/

Only odd thing is that the toFixed method (in Chrome at least) will not round exact halves up, but down. For instance if you run this code:

```
var test = 2.55;
alert(test.toFixed(1));
```

It will print '2.5' and not '2.6' like you expect. However if you run this code:

```
var test = 2.5;
alert(test.toFixed(0));
```

It will print 3. So be aware of that.

Comment: The function you list only works for numbers less than 1. If, instead of using (Math.abs(n)) you just use -n, it will work for values >1 too, mapping e.g. 155.0002 to 1.55 x 10^2.