# Large number in javascript

Tags: javascript, numbers, ecmascript-5

I am working on a calculator in javascript, where user can enter the values in textfield and operation will be performed. 
Now if user enters a very large value
for example 5345345345353453453453535 
it is converted to 5.345345345353453e+24

I am using parsrInt() to convert it to integers. and it gives me 5. 
which is wrong .
Can anybody suggest how to solve it?

Comment: This might be useful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11124451/how-can-i-convert-numbers-into-scientific-notation

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to deal with big numbers in javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4288821/how-to-deal-with-big-numbers-in-javascript)

Answer (score 3):

Integers in javascript are, like every numbers, stored as [IEEE754](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754) double precision floats.

So you can only exactly store integers up to 2^51 (the size of the mantissa).

This means you'll have to design another format for dealing with big integers, or to use an existing library like [BigInteger.js](https://github.com/peterolson/BigInteger.js) (Google will suggest a few other ones).

Answer (score 2):

Taken from [Mozilla documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt):

> Parses a string argument and returns an integer of the specified radix
>   or base.

Therefore `parseInt()` is taking your value as a string `5.345345345353453e+24`

It is then ignoring any non-integer values and classing this as a decimal (5.345...) and then evaluating this to `5`.

---

As [@dystroy](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15005795/370103) has pointed out, if you wish to carry out calculations with these large numbers you'll need to use a custom format, or use a pre-existing javascript library.

Answer (score 0):

Try parseFloat instead of parseInt.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var value = parseFloat(5345345345353453453453535);
    alert(value);
</script>
```

Comment: This won't give you `5345345345353453453453535` but only the rounded value.