# How to make javascript round sensitive to number of digits in value?

Tags: javascript

Say we had an array [0.09, 870, 499] and we want to get array values round so: [0.1, 1000, 100]?

What have I tried:

```
var logarithmicRound = function(val) {
 var degree =  Math.round(Math.log(val) / Math.LN10);

    if(Math.pow(10, degree) - val > val) {
        --degree;
    }
    return Math.pow(10, degree);
};

console.log(logarithmicRound(0.05));
console.log(logarithmicRound(0.7));
console.log(logarithmicRound(49));
console.log(logarithmicRound(50));
console.log(logarithmicRound(400));
console.log(logarithmicRound(800));

// prints
//0.1
//1 
//10
//100
//100
//1000
```

Yet it seems quite ugly... yet it does exactly what I need.

Comment: Have you tried anything? Or you just hoped we'd do your homework/assignment/work for you?

Comment: Please describe the rounding rules, Why does 499 round to 100?

Comment: @AlexK. - I didn't even spot that :)

Answer (score 1):

I use a couple of functions for rounding numbers, they might be useful.

```
function roundTo2(value){
return (Math.round(value * 100) / 100);
}



function roundResult(value, places){
    var multiplier = Math.pow(10, places);
    return (Math.round(value * multiplier) / multiplier);
}
```

You'll obviously need to round numbers and put into the array / extract, round, put back - not as efficient as someone elses answer may be

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you wish to round up to the nearest power of 10 (and that your example of 499 rounding to 100 is incorrect):

```
var rounded = myArray.map(function(n) {
    return Math.pow(10, Math.ceil(Math.log(n) / Math.LN10));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

From the given example it looks like @DuckQueen wants to round off to nearest power of 10..

Here is the algo -

```
1. Represent each number N in scientific notation S. Lets say S is n*10^x
2. Let A =(N - (10 power x)) and B=((10 pow x+1) - N)
3. if A<B N = 10^x otherwise N=10^(x+1)
```

You may assume one way or the other for the case A==B

Use this for Step 1:

- [How can I convert numbers into scientific notation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11124451/how-can-i-convert-numbers-into-scientific-notation)