# How do I format a number in scientific notation to show less digits in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

For example, I have a number which is 1.3685999999999998e+35 but I just want to display 1.368e+35. I tried toFixed and toPrecision but nothing works.

Comment: Possible Duplicate  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11124451/how-can-i-convert-numbers-into-scientific-notation

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use [`Number.prototype.toExponential`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toExponential):

```js
var x = 11827361827361872361263812631827361823618723;
console.log(x.toExponential(2));
console.log(x.toExponential(3));
console.log(x.toExponential(10));
```