# How to convert an Integer to a "powernumber"

Tags: javascript, node.js

Okay hear me out, i know this might be a dumb question and there is probably a nice easy solution to this, but english is not my native language and i can't for the love of me find out what to even search on google or here for this problem.

The gist of it is, that i have a really simple discord bot running on Nodejs with Discord.js V14.
I have a const that is defined as an integer. I want to convert this integer to a "powernumber" (these: ³ ¹ ⁴)

Is there any way this is even possible in a clean way?

I didn't really try anything yet, since i don't even know where to start. But what im trying to do is basically this

```
const number = "3"

//some node js magic that converts ³ to ³
```

if the ³ gets output as a string, that would be optimal, since i want to use that in a nickname like for example:

```
const user = interaction.options.getMember('user')

user.setNickname('nickname${number}'
```

I again appologise for not being able to explain exactly what i want. As i said earlier, english is not my native language :/

Comment: You'll want to look at your post and then hit [edit] to fix all that bad markdown. That said: make it a power _where_? In an HTML string? In unicode text? What is going to actually display it?

Comment: I mean there's only 10 of those, you can just hardcode them.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I convert numbers into scientific notation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11124451/how-can-i-convert-numbers-into-scientific-notation)

Comment: Are you just asking how to do `'4'.replace('4', '⁴')` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`replace`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) with a callback function that will read out the superscript from a string:

```js
const turnDigitsToSuperscript = (s) => s.replace(/\d/g, d => "⁰¹²³⁴⁵⁶⁷⁸⁹"[d]);

// Example:
const s = "test123"
console.log(turnDigitsToSuperscript(s));
```

Comment: Using an array is a good idea. Wouldn’t have expected the string `d` to cast to integer for array lookup but that is JS for you!

Comment: Thank you! This is exactly what i wanted and needed :D

Comment: @user9540018, there is no array here, and JavaScript keys are always *strings* (or symbols). So it is the other way round: integer indices are coerced to strings.

Comment: Well I have leant something new! Thanks @trincot